# Elegant way to evaluate $\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\left(M+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\;\sin\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta}{\sin^2(\theta/2)}d\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

Solve in terms of $M, N$
$$I(M. N) = \int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\left[\left(M + \frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right]\sin\left[\left(N + \frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right]}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}d\theta$$
where $M, N$ are non-negative integers.

I've tried solving it by using trigonometric identities and brute force, but it gets extremely annoying. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: See [MSE-$\texttt{MathJax}$-$\LaTeX$ Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Show us what trignometric identities you tried and how far have you reached in your solution. This will help you get more attention to your question from the MSE community

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.\vphantom{\Large A}\mrm{I}\pars{M,N}\,
\right\vert_{\ M, N\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\large\ \geq 0}}} \equiv
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{\bracks{M + 1/2}\theta}
\sin\pars{\bracks{N + 1/2}\theta} \over \sin^{2}\pars{\theta/2}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\cos\pars{\bracks{M - N}\theta}
-\cos\pars{\bracks{M + N + 1}\theta} \over \sin^{2}\pars{\theta/2}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}{1 - \cos\pars{\bracks{M + N + 1}\theta} \over \sin^{2}\pars{\theta/2}}\,\dd\theta -
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}{1 - \cos\pars{\verts{M - N}\theta} \over \sin^{2}\pars{\theta/2}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\mc{J}\pars{M + N + 1} - \mc{J}\pars{\verts{M - N}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] &\ \mbox{where}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\left.\vphantom{\Large A}\mc{J}\pars{a}
\,\right\vert_{\ a\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{1 - \cos\pars{2a\theta} \over \sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
\\[2mm]
& \ds{=} & \ds{\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{1 + 2\ic a\theta - \expo{2\ic a\theta} \over \sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> Lets evaluate $\ds{\mrm{J}\pars{a}}$:

\begin{align}
\mc{J}\pars{a} & =
\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{1 + 2\ic a\theta - \expo{2\ic a\theta} \over \sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\Re\int_{\theta\ =\ 0}^{\theta\ =\ \pi/2}
{1 + 2\ic a\bracks{-\ic\ln\pars{z}} - z^{2a} \over
-\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{2}/\pars{4z^{2}}}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic\theta}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.4\,\Im\int_{\theta\ =\ 0}^{\theta\ =\ \pi/2}
{z^{2a} - 2a\ln\pars{z} - 1 \over
\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{2}}\,z\,\dd z
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic\theta}}
\\[5mm] & =
-4\,\Im\int_{1}^{0}
{y^{2a}\expo{\ic\pars{2a}\pi/2} - 2a\bracks{\ln\pars{y} + \ic\pi/2} - 1 \over
\pars{1 + y^{2}}^{2}}\pars{\ic y}\,\ic\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
-4\int_{0}^{1}
{y^{2a}\
\overbrace{\sin\pars{\pi a}}^{\ds{\color{red}{=\ 0}}}\ -\
\pi a \over
\pars{1 + y^{2}}^{2}}\,y\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{y^{2}\ \mapsto\ y}{=}\,\,\,
2\pi a\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over\pars{1 + y}^{2}} = \bbx{\pi a}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> With \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}:

$$
\bbx{\mrm{I}\pars{M,N} =
\pi\pars{M + N + 1 - \verts{M - N}}}
$$

Answer (score 6):

### Hint

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}1+2\sum _{n=1}^{N}\cos(n\theta )&={\frac {\sin \left(\left(N+{\frac {1}{2}}\right)\theta \right)}{\sin \left({\frac {\theta }{2}}\right)}}\end{aligned}}}$$
and use the following fact
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(n \theta)\cos(m \theta)d \theta=0$$
when $$m \ne n$$